# Issue with Wiley NJDv5 template for reference entries with single authorship

Tags: bst, wiley-article

I'm using wileyNJD-Chicago.bst as required by my targeted journal and I installed the **WileyNJD-v5** class downloaded from the zip provided by wiley website (2022/04/05 v5).

When I use with natbib citep, citet or just cite and in @article and the author entry has no 'and' because the author is just one, I got an error message like:
"**You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry kahn2018**"
When inspecting the file name.blg there is a report about the error, but without any additional info:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
> Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003 The
> top-level auxiliary file: output.aux The style file:
> wileyNJD-Chicago.bst Database file #1: refs.bib Reallocated
> wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000. You can't pop an
> empty literal stack for entry kahn2018 while executing---line 1864 of
> file wileyNJD-Chicago.bst You can't pop an empty literal stack for
> entry kitchenham2004 while executing---line 1864 of file
> wileyNJD-Chicago.bst You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry
> sauer2018digital while executing---line 1864 of file
> wileyNJD-Chicago.bst You've used 23 entries,
> 3221 wiz_defined-function locations,
> 818 strings with 9358 characters, and the built_in function-call counts, 17273 in all, are:
> = -- 1396
>
> > -- 1478
> > < -- 0
>
> - -- 458
>
> - -- 506
>
> - -- 1694
>   := -- 3207  add.period$ -- 66  call.type$ -- 23  change.case$ -- 161
>   chr.to.int$ -- 23  cite$ -- 23  duplicate$ -- 397  empty$ -- 931
>   format.name$ -- 574  if$ -- 3152  int.to.chr$ -- 1  int.to.str$ -- 0
>
> > missing$ -- 20  newline$ -- 114  num.names$ -- 231  pop$ -- 128  preamble$ -- 1  purify$ -- 321  quote$ -- 0  skip$ -- 439  stack$ -- 0
> > substring$ -- 834  swap$ -- 114  text.length$ -- 0  text.prefix$ -- 0
> > top$ -- 0  type$ -- 455  warning$ -- 0  while$ -- 228  width$ -- 0
> > write$ -- 298  (There were 3 error messages)

So, I have no clear idea how to get this issue fixed.
I've found that if I add another author the error is not longer there, but this only help in the diagnosis of the issue.

Any hint provided would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

BTW, the line 1864 of wileyNJD-Chicago.bst looks like:

> ITERATE {call.type$}

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: make a minimal example that demonstrates the error and then sent it to the maintainer of the class/bibtex style.